# PHP session database class and garbage collection with saved logins

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, garbage-collection

I'm using a simple, custom session wrapper class to store user sessions in the database, but I'm confused with how to accomplish long-term saved sessions while having short term sessions as well.

I give the user the option to "Keep me logged in". If this is set then I want to keep their session saved for 6 months. If it's not set then I want to keep their session saved for 2 hours. I don't want this 6 month period to keep extending... even if they log in every day, after 6 months their persistent login will be cleared.

If I set `session.cookie_lifetime` and the garage collection variable `session.gc_maxlifetime` to something like 6 months or more, then the people with only the "2 hour session" will be leaving tons of unused sessions that won't get cleaned up by the garbage collection until 6 months or more. I'd rather keep `session.gc_maxlifetime` set to a more reasonable value.

I'm thinking what I should do is create a cookie (not the PHPSESSID cookie because I don't want garbage collection to clear it) that contains the last used session id, and set the expiration of that cookie to either 6 months or 2 hours, depending on if they checked "Keep me logged in" or not. If someone starts a new session and they have this cookie saved, it will try to match the cookie's session id to a saved session in the database. If the same session is found, it will change the session id to their new session id and update the database record, continuing their session. If it's not found it will create a new database entry.

Does this sound like a good way to accomplish what I want? Are there any security issues with this?

Comment: There are obvious security issues with having a 6 month session no matter how you do it, so hopefully security is not very important to your site.

Comment: If there are security issues with 6 months, then there are issues with 1 week. If someone is wanting to keep themselves logged in, there are obvious risks they are taking. And no, security is not a major factor on this website. Just making sure I'm not doing anything dumb.